# Javascript Check if class already exists

Tags: javascript

Hello i need to check in constructor if the class already exists how can I do this?

i have something like this:

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || { 

    MyClass: function(string){
     this.string = string;
     this.sayHello = function(){
        return this.string;
     }
   }

};
```

Comment: If `MyNamespace` doesn't exist, how could `MyClass` possibly exist?

Comment: There are no classes in javascript. All native functions are constructors, so if the function exists, then so does the "class".

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "class" there are no classes in JavaScript. Is it the prototype or an object.

Comment: I know there are no classes guys, but You can simulate a class by using a function

Comment: I just want to return the same object if the object is already there

Comment: whatever lets call the class with the more appropriate name 'object'

Comment: I think what you have written is fine, is it not?

Comment: @Mardoxx Im checking the namespace but not the MyClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};
MyNamespace.MyClass = MyNamespace.MyClass || function(string){
    this.string = string;
    this.sayHello = function(){
        return this.string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain when you would use that? I wonder how it might be possible that a prototype might be initiaized twice? (This question is not meant critical, I'm just curious).

Comment: If you're for some reason not sure that `MyClass` exists. When your project is set up properly, this shouldn't be a problem though.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was meant :D Thanks a lot!

Comment: So this is rather a workaround and not a common practice?

Comment: It is the most common way used to check if a variable exists.